# How to make ffmpeg exit when rtmp input stream ends?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I am using ffmpeg to transcode a stream from my local nginx rtmp server, and send the transcoded media back to the same local rtmp server. When the stream goes offline, ffmpeg stays active. When the stream starts again, ffmpeg picks up the transcoding work.

I'd like ffmpeg to exit when the input rtmp stream stops, but I cannot find out to configure it to do that. I've looked through the manual page and the online documentation.

For completeness, these are the arguments I currectly provide to ffmpeg:

> ffmpeg -i 'rtmp://localhost/live/ijsbeer' -s '1280x720' -vcodec 'libx264' -preset 'veryfast' -crf '25' -maxrate '2000k' -bufsize '1000.0k' -force_key_frames '0:00:02' -max_muxing_queue_size '4096' -acodec 'copy' -copyts -copytb '0' -f 'flv' 'rtmp://localhost/live/ijsbeer_720p'

Making ffmpeg exit itself solves two of my problems. Firstly, ffmpeg sometimes experiences non-monotonous DTS issues when the encoder (OBS) streaming to the rtmp server restarts. Second, I'd like to implement a basic monitoring system to notify me of issues in the transcoder. Making ffmpeg exit when the input stream stops seems like to most reliable way to determine if ffmpeg is doing work. Parsing the stderr/stdout isn't reliable as there is no clear output format.

When transcoding I receive these regular stderr lines:

> frame=  241 fps= 30 q=30.0 size=      38kB time=00:00:09.74 bitrate=  32.0kbits/s speed= 1.2x

Which pause when I stop the source stream. There is no log output stating the source stream has exited.